# From Jsp to EXTjs

Tags: jsp, extjs

i pass a var from my servlet to my jsp without problem, but i need to pass then the same var form my jsp to my js. Is this possible?

My servlet code is the next:

```
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)   throws ServletException, IOException 
        {
           String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, "El usuario que usa esto es " + usuario );

           request.setAttribute("usuario",usuario);
           RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("/jsp/PantallasGestion/tipoPapel.jsp");
           rd.forward(request,response);
        }
```

Then my jsp is:

```
         <head>
         <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/ext-all.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript"       src="js/PantallasGestion/tipoPapel.js"></script>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/ext-all- gray.css"/>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/EstiloPrincipal.css"/>
         <title>Tipo Papel</title>

   </head>
   <body leftmargin="3" topmargin="3" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0"
        bottommargin="0">
         <form name="form1" action="/MyMaver/GestorPeticiones" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div id="campos"></div>
    </form>

          <%String name = (String)request.getAttribute("usuario"); %>
        <%= name%>
      </body>
```

And finally i must past this var (usuario) to my EXTjs. My problem is that i dont know how to pass from jsp to another js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a hidden input in your jsp:

```
<input type="hidden" name="usuario" id="usuario" value="<%=request.getAttribute("usuario")%>">
```

Catch it in your js:

```
var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").value;
```

And depending on what you're trying to accomplish, you could assign it to an element value:

```
fieldLabel: 'Usuario',
name: 'usuario',
value: usuario,
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I solved including my js in my jsp and pass the var, thanks anyway.

Comment: You should post your answer for others with the same problem, just saying anyaway. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you want to achieve. But I think you are doing all in wrong way. Just guessing.

To solve your problem. Put your value in an html element and read the value from your javascript.

```
   <div id="usuario">${requestScope.usuario}</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var usuario = document.getElementById("usuario").innerHTML;
// pass usuario to your EXTjs function 
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is that i canot use html... my web application is integer in a web page where i can only put in the js my window.open servlet passing a var (get method),in my servlet i pass this var to my jsp, but i need to pass then to my javascript in EXTjs, this is now my problem, in my servlet i can not use the var because my servlets works in post method with my EXTjs...